# How to sort sqlite database in android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I need to display list of 10 best scores.
I used this code to get the data and put it in a arraylist

```
private ArrayList<String> getData() {
    String[] columns = {DbHelper.COL_NAME, DbHelper.COL_SCORE};
    Cursor c = db.query(DbHelper.TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, DbHelper.COL_SCORE, "10");
    int nameCol = c.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.COL_NAME);
    int scoreCol = c.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.COL_SCORE);
    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
        scoresList.add(c.getString(nameCol) + " " + c.getString(scoreCol));
    }

    return scoresList;
}
```

The only problem that its ordered from the lowest score to the highest, and i need it reversed.

Comment: Add an `ORDER BY Score DESC` clause (by default, the `ORDER BY` statement operates as if you specified `ASC`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with below query...

```
Cursor c = db.query(DbHelper.TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, DbHelper.COL_SCORE +" DESC", "10");
```